# Automatically set one to many id when adding items

Tags: cakephp

I have two tables with the following (simplified) structure

- person_availabilities (id, person_id)
- persons (id)

that are related (a person can have many availabilities)

I have used the bake feature to create the current pages.

What I wish to do is go to a person's profile and click on "New Person Availability". The page will then go to the add person availabilities page and allow the user to input the data there.

The user should not have to find the person in a drop down list, which is the default way to select the identity of the person whose availability I'm setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to a person's profile and then navigate to add page, try to pass the id of that person through url to that add page and then try following:

URL may be:

```
http://example.com/person_availabilities/add/2 // here 2 is the person id
```

In person_availabilities controller's add function try something like this:

```
function add($person_id = null) { // $person_id is the passed id. e.g $person_id = 2

   $this->set('person_id', $person_id); // set the id to view

}
```

In view file the select box should automatically show the person whose availability you're using if the select field name is `person_id` i.e.

```
$this->Form->input('person_id');
```

If not then try `selected` property to that select box:

```
$this->Form->input('FIELD_NAME', array('selected' => $person_id));
```

Comment: Thank you! I had managed to arrive to the url and add($person_id) conclusion, but I didn't manage to make it to the input part.